# Api 28 class is called from androidx's support library

Tags: android, exception, android-support-library, androidx

I'm getting this when trying to run debug mode on my android phone.

It's reasonable why application can't find `OnUnhandledKeyEventListener` as it was added in api 28 and my phone runs api 27, but why it even tries, when it's supposed to be a support library? Is it a bug in library or am I missing something? This happens even if you create empty android studio project and do refactor -> migrate to AndroidX

```
    I/zygote64: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2422)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:141)
        at void com.infradev.lessontimer.LoginActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (LoginActivity.java:25)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7084)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7075)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2767)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1613)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:171)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6635)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:823)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/ap
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2422)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:141)
        at void com.infradev.lessontimer.LoginActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (LoginActivity.java:25)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7084)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7075)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2767)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1613)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:171)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6635)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:823)
    Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2422)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:141)
        at void com.infradev.lessontimer.LoginActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (LoginActivity.java:25)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7084)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7075)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2767)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1613)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:171)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6635)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:823)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/ap
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2422)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:141)
        at void com.infradev.lessontimer.LoginActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (LoginActivity.java:25)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7084)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7075)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2767)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1613)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:171)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6635)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:823)
I/zygote64: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2422)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:141)
        at void com.infradev.lessontimer.LoginActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (LoginActivity.java:25)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7084)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7075)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2767)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1613)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:171)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6635)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:823)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.infradev.lessontimer-oANosPd_Q6S3fKsdUvgGLg==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/ap
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2422)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:141)
        at void com.infradev.lessontimer.LoginActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (LoginActivity.java:25)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7084)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7075)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2767)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1613)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:171)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6635)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it a bug in library or I'm missing something?

This is a **information** message from the zygote (`I/zygote64`). This is not an error. There is nothing wrong.

You will get this sort of message when a class is loaded (`ViewCompat`) that has references to unrecognized symbols (`View.OnUnhandledKeyEventListener`), even if the code will not attempt to use those symbols.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was crazy helpful! I thought that this exception stops the dubugger, but after your reply I realized it doesn't. However it must be some sort of bug since acording to this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120750246, it has been fixed in canary build